# Android: Application not visible on some countries

Tags: android, google-play

I have a free Android application in Play Store. One of my user from Maldives(a country) complained that he is not able to download the app. Error Message: "App is not available for your country".

I checked All Countries in my developer account. Maldives is not available in the country list. User is getting my other competitor apps.

Can any one tell me how to fix this?

Comment: could be some weird local  perk -   some time ago games were no available in korea generally, because korean game board has special requirements to display age guidance symbol ( even if there is no minimal age ) -  so no games for korea but other apps are ok.   Maybe your application  kind is deemed unappropriate by maledivian authoritorities

Comment: My competitor app is under the same category like me. But that is available for Maldives. I'm in a very critical situation to fix it immediately.

Comment: What was it at the end?